# how to pass output parameter to ms-sql stored procedure using knex

Tags: node.js, knex.js

how to pass output parameter to ms-sql stored procedure using knex Query builder.

we are using Knex in node js to call MS-SQL raw query and stored procedure. In MS-SQL, we can pass both IN and OUTPUT parameter in stored procedure. Now, i am stuck, how to pass output parameter to ms-sql stored procedure.
Procedure parameter is like this :

```
exec sp_procedurename 'username',@RecCount OUTPUT,'',1,30,''
```

Answer (score 0):

`node-mssql` driver has pretty custom syntax for that (https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#execute-procedure-callback). As far as I know that API cannot be accessed through knex.